# Facebook sdk for Android - Get friends' Staus

Tags: android

How can I get status of all of my **facebook** Friends using **Facebook** SDK. Here is my code,but is return error.

```
Request r = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
                    new Request.GraphUserListCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(List users,
                    Response response) {                        


                try{
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
                    Log.d("data", jsonObject.toString(0));

                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){

                        JSONObject friend = array.getJSONObject(i);

                    }
                }catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
        Bundle params = r.getParameters();

        params.putString("fields", "name,statuses.limit(5)");
        r.setParameters(params);
        r.executeAsync();
```

Comment: What error is it returning?

Comment: It is not return error at the moment but it is showing only id & names of my friends not the statuses.